# Top 10% of our candidate pool,

Tags: american-english, phrase-meaning, percentages

I got a message from a company, in which they said "you're in the top 10% of our candidate pool".
Please, what does that mean?

Comment: If there are 50 people in the "pool" of candidates, you are one of the top 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means they are telling you that

- they have multiple candidates, not just you (they have a "candidate pool")
- they have a ranking system to rank the candidates, including you
- your rank is within the top 10% out of the total size of the candidate pool

This type of message is often meant to be encouraging, and hints that you may have a good chance of receiving a job offer.